# Script to search “.exe” & “.msi” Part II

Tags: batch-file

My Script does not filter "Program Files" & "WinNT" from scanning,
and Timer script couldn't run at all.

```
@Echo Off
@Echo Scanning In Progress... This Will Take Several Time!! 
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set starttime=%time%

cd\
set Directory=Directory
set Date Created=Date Created
set Date Modified=Date Modified
set Date Accessed=Date Accessed
set FileName=FileName

Echo %Directory%,%Date Created%,%Date Modified%,%Date Accessed%,%FileName% >>c:\users\user\desktop\Result.csv

For /r "c:\" %%a in ("*.exe" "*.msi") DO (
set "d=%%a"
if /i not "!d:~0,17!"=="c:\program files\" if /i not "!d:~0,9!"=="c:\WinNT\" (
@Echo %%a
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=] " %%b in ('dir /tc "%%a" ^|find /n " "    ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "datecreated=%%c  %%d%%e"
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=] " %%f in ('dir /tw "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "datemodified=%%g  %%h%%i"
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=] " %%j in ('dir /ta "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "dateaccessed=%%k  %%l%%m"
For /f "tokens=6 delims=] " %%n in ('dir /tc "%%a" ^|find /n " " ^|find "[6]"') DO SET "filename=%%n"

Echo "%%a",!datecreated!,!datemodified!,!dateaccessed!,!filename! >>c:\users\user\desktop\Result.csv 
)
)
set endtime=%time%

set /a hrs=%endtime:~0,2%
set /a hrs=%hrs%-%starttime:~0,2%

set /a mins=%endtime:~3,2%
set /a mins=%mins%-%starttime:~3,2%

set /a secs=%endtime:~6,2%
set /a secs=%secs%-%starttime:~6,2%

if %secs% lss 0 (
    set /a secs=!secs!+60
    set /a mins=!mins!-1
)
if %mins% lss 0 (
    set /a mins=!mins!+60
    set /a hrs=!hrs!-1
)
if %hrs% lss 0 (
    set /a hrs=!hrs!+24
)
set /a tot=%secs%+%mins%*60+%hrs%*3600

Echo Start = %starttime%
Echo End   = %endtime%
Echo Hours = %hrs%
Echo Minutes = %mins%
Echo Seconds = %secs%
Echo Total = %tot%
Echo Scanning Progress Compeleted!!
Endlocal 
@pause
```

Comment: This Script was not able to run successfully on WinNT OS. It still scanning "Program Files" & "WinNT" folders.  

set "d=%%a"
if /i not "!d:~0,17!"=="c:\program files\" if /i not "!d:~0,11!"=="c:\windows\" (

Comment: The Timer script does not work on WinNT as well. Please help.

Comment: I suggest debugging your script by removing the `@echo off'` and seeing where it errors.  Then ask a specific question about a particular line or block of code.

Comment: Error message: set /a hrs=:~0.2  Missing Operator

Comment: The colon and tilde are used to create sub strings of the contents of a variable. The /A option is used for evaluating an expression. In layman's terms that is basically math. If you are trying to do a substring, the help file clearly states to use a comma to separate the arguments for the substring. If you are trying to do math, you also need to realize that cmd.exe can only accept 32 bit integers.

Comment: It is for counting the time taken to run the cmd.. How can I correct my script then?

Comment: Why is it able to run on WinXP but cannot run on WinNT